# rvizlib ImageDisplay cannot find Ogre resources

Tags: ros, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified the librviz tutorial to use an ImageDisplay:

```
  // Create image display
  image_ = dynamic_cast<rviz::ImageDisplay*>( 
      manager_->createDisplay("rviz/Image", "image", true )->getDisplay() );
  image_->setTopic("/gscam/image_raw");
```

But when I run the program, the Ogre subsystem fails to find any of the resources, despite the fact that the resource loading calls in rivz::RenderSystem do in fact get called:

```
Texture: SelectionRect0Texture: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8A8,1x1x1) with 0 generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,1x1x1.
Texture: SelectionManagerFallbackMaterialPickTexture: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,1x1x1) with 0 generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,1x1x1.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::FileNotFoundException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource no_image.png in resource group General or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
```

Are the resources being unloaded somewhere, or do I need to do something else to make sure they're loaded?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34799/rvizlib-imagedisplay-cannot-find-ogre-resources/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-07-04**:
Hi, when you are doing it, your image is the same window or it's in another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the "textures" directory just wasn't being loaded. A ticket has been submitted to fix this bug: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5453

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1